# C# get localVariable with Reflection

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.reflection

I study and test System.Reflection.

It gets the error when calling `GetValue()` with `property`.

I considered that it would turn `property` from `PropertyInfo` into `string`.
But, something is wrong here.

```
     var asmArray = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

     //to find the specified assembly
     var asm = asmArray.FirstOrDefault(asm => string.Equals(asm.GetName().Name, "TestAspNetCoret00")); 

     //to find the specified class
     var type = asm.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(type => string.Equals(type.Name, "StudentRespository"));

     //to find the specified method
     var methodInfo = type.GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(mI => string.Equals(mI.Name, "GetById")); 

     //to find the specified localVariable
     var localVariableInfo = methodInfo.GetMethodBody().LocalVariables.FirstOrDefault(lI => string.Equals(lI.LocalType.GetTypeInfo().Name, "SqlCommand")); 

     //to find the specified property of the localVariable
     var property = localVariableInfo.LocalType.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties.FirstOrDefault(pro => string.Equals(pro.Name, "CommandText")); 

     if (property != null)
     {
     Console.WriteLine((string)property.GetValue(localVariableInfo.LocalType)); 
     // error! TargetException: Object does not match target type.
     }
```

Comment: You're trying to get the *value* of a local variable, using reflection? Local variables only *exist* when the method which contains them is executing. If I have the method `void Foo(int x) { int localVariable = x; }`, your code will find the `localVariable` variable, but what is its value? Asking the question makes no sense, because it depends on what value of `x` you passed into `Foo`

Comment: Thanks for ur advice, canton7. Does C# support to get the localVariables from stackFrame when the method is executing? I studied the docs for `stackFrame` class , but I didnt find any relative stuffs.

Comment: No. Bear in mind that the multiple local variables might be re-using the same slot in `LocalVariables`, and the JIT might remove the local variable entirely (and frequently does in Release code)